# Some good ways to roast vegetables without using oil?

Tags: cooking, vegetables

What are some good ways to roast vegetables - such as carrots, cauliflower, peppers, or celery - without using oil? Crispy would be nice; tasty required! :-)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Exchange. I think you could get better anwswers to your question on [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/). :)

Comment: @AlexanderRossa I considered migrating it, but it reads like a recipe request (which they would close) unfortunately.

Comment: @Erica doesn't sound like a recipe request to me, this is about methods. And really not vegetarianism specific, since roasted vegetable dishes with or without oil are commonly vegan or vegetarian. Expect some legit "don't!" answers on SA though. The oil serves multiple functions - steam barrier, heat buffer, taste balancer(!), substrate for some of the flavors from the aromatics, pan protection....

Answer (score 1):

There is a ton of recipes on a google search

One I suggest - https://www.forksoverknives.com/plant-based-cooking-how-to-cook-without-oil/#gs._knr2Zk

> Choose Your Oil-Free Cooking Method
>
> 1. Sautéing and stir-frying—The most common question I get on this topic is how to sauté or stir-fry without butter or oil. The trick is
>      to use small amounts of water or broth, adding just a small amount (1
>      to 2 tablespoons) at a time. Do this as often as needed to cook and
>      brown the food, without steaming it. Also, remember to toss and stir
>      the food periodically with a wooden spoon so that it doesn’t burn.
> 2. Baking—You can use a fruit purée as a healthy (and delicious!) substitute for fats like oil, butter, or shortening. Some of my
>      favorites include applesauce, mashed bananas, and puréed dates. In
>      some instances, nut flour or nut butters can serve as substitutions or
>      additions.
> 3. Roasting—There’s no need to coat your vegetables or other foods with oil before roasting them in the oven. They might take a little
>      longer, but they will eventually brown and roast nicely. Before
>      placing them in the oven, I like to season my vegetables with spices,
>      herbs, and either a little vegetable stock or a light water-soy sauce
>      mixture.
> 4. Deep frying alternative—It may take a little getting used to, but I’m confident that you will come to enjoy the not-greasy but still
>      delicious (and far healthier) choice to bake your potatoes and veggies
>      instead of deep frying them. You can even bake up delicious (eggless)
>      breaded patties or veggies by lightly dipping them in a slurry of
>      arrowroot powder or cornstarch mixed with either water or unsweetened,
>      unflavored plant milk, and then coating them with whole-grain bread
>      crumbs or cornmeal. Use nonstick, silicone, or parchment-lined baking
>      sheets to achieve a crispy outer crust.

See site for additional tips.

Comment: If on an expert Q&A site you want to recommend performing a Google websearch, you should be able to post an answer better than this having presumably done precisely that. 1 has nothing to do with roasting; it is unclear what the difference is between 2 (roasting) and 3 (baking) unless we are talking about potatoes (a roast potato has been peeled; a baked one hasn't); the nut butter mentioned in 2 contains oil; and 4 seems to be saying "bake stuff rather than deep-frying it". This list is terribly confused, but perhaps a useful answer could be constructed from some of the ideas in it.

Comment: I posted after the question went 2 days without an answer. Baking is typically setting the over at say 350 while roasting is typically setting the over on high. #2 mentions more than nut oil. #4 has a number of suggestions. If you feel you can do better go for it. Perhaps close the original question as too broad or too little research before asking i am sure there are hundreds or thousands of options / recipes here.

Comment: @ruffle Your question as it stands is, as noted, rather broad. What exactly are you looking for besides "just don't add oil when roasting"?

Comment: @ruffle - You are welcome to be a part of the community or not. I think the problem is your question is very broad and there is not much of a technical answer other than use something other than oil.